# How do I set a route in hash mode with params with Vue Router 3 (Vue 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Currently, my Vue router is using hash mode for my router and I am looking for a way to pass parameters when generating links to another component. so far I came up with this:

this is what it currently looks like in my Markup:

```html
<b-button variant="primary" class="rounded-0" :href="'/article/' + article.id" >View post</b-button>
```

I am passing down the article id into the link so that when the user clicks on the button, it will direct him to a component where the article with the respective id is visible with its content.

the problem comes when setting up routes, below is my index.js under router

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Main from '@/views/Main.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [

  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Main',
    component: Main
  },

  {
    path: '/menu',
    name: 'Menu',
    component: ()=> import('../views/Menu.vue')
  },

  {
    path:'/cart',
    name:'Cart',
    component: () => import('../views/Purchase.vue')
  },

  {
    path:'/blog',
    name:'Blog',
    component: () => import('../views/Blog.vue')
  },
  {
    path:'/article/:id',
    component: ()=> import('../views/ArticlePage.vue')
  }
  // {
  //   path: '/about',
  //   name: 'About',
  //   // route level code-splitting
  //   // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
  //   // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
  //   component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  // }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

As you can see for the /article/:id path I am trying to link it with the ArticlePageComponent. The problem is that /article/:id doesn't seem to work for hash modes, it will just redirect me to the homepage. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's unclear if the problem was isolated. " in production" was mentioned but it's unclear if the same code works correctly in development and with createWebHistory . There's a inconsistency, /article/:id was mentioned but with no example route or url. A link would be `#/article/1`, this isn't used anywhere. It's impractical to use `href` for router links, that's what RouterLink comp is for

Comment: @EstusFlask, I Edited my question so that its clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having `href` in `b-button` why don't have a handler in methods like

```
routePage(article) {
  this.$router.push({
   path: `/article/${article.id}`
  });
}
```

and trigger it on click event

```
<b-button variant="primary" class="rounded-0" @click="routePage(article)" >View post</b-button>
```